# how to pass a data to a input VALUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input box with a empty value. I want to be able to pass data to input box VALUE

```html
<input type="text" value="" class="box">
```

```js
$('.skills-tags').on('click', function(){
    var value = $(".skills-tags").val(); 
    $('.label-primary').append(value);
});
```

I want to be able to append the value of `.skills-tags` to the value of my input box.

Comment: What is `.skill-tags`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the original value and *append* something to the end of it, do it like this:

```
$('.label-primary').attr('value', $('.label-primary').attr('value') + value);
```

Or:

```
$('.label-primary').val($('.label-primary').val() + value);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `attr` method:

```
$(".box").attr('value', value);
```

first argument is tag attribute, second is attribute value to set

or use `val` method:

```
$('input.box').val(value);
```

Comment: This is not right...`input` uses the `.val()` method.

Comment: Why? If it's an input, $(".box").val(value);

Answer (score 1):

To pass a value to an input you can use the `val()` method -

```
$('input.box').val('this is a new value');
```

This value will be given to every input with a class of 'box';